# Using Sqlplus to insert procedure names into a table

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

Hi am using SQLPlus to develop an oracle database.The problem is that I intend to insert a procedure name into a table called available procedures. The problem is that once I write the name of the procedure to be inserted/updated it executes.Now, the procedure itself has a return which is an integer hence the reason for the error. How can I use SQLPlus to insert this procedure name?

Comment: Second, you should ask in a manner that give us an ideea of what happens in your code. You should give examples that make us able to reproduce your problem, etc.

Comment: This is strange: _"once I write the name of the procedure to be inserted/updated it executes"_. You have a trigger? Procedures do not return anything, Funtions return something...

Answer (score 4):

If you are trying to insert the **name** of a procedure, simply enclose it in single quotes:

```
insert into available_procedures (procedure_name) values ('MY_PROCEDURE');
```

and not:

```
insert into available_procedures (procedure_name) values (MY_PROCEDURE);
```

since this will (as you found) attempt to **run** MY_PROCEDURE

Comment: +1 for giving a sensible answer to an extremly unclear question

Comment: where my_procedure is a function :)